# Gnostice PDFToolKit vcl - filling digital signature form field

Tags: delphi, pdf, digital-signature, vcl

We are currently looking at the Gnostice product that offers feature of filling digital signature to an empty e-signature pdf form field.

We use the Digital Signature demo to test out the functionality using our PDF form, but all we got from the output is blank signed form. The properties of the signature indicates it is signed correctly, but it's blank on the form. We would like to know what is causing this.

Also, our PDF form has 3 digital signature form fields. 2 of them are filled by our customers, but the 3rd one we need to sign. The 2 valid signed e-signatures when processed through the Digital Signature demo, they became invalid. We also want to know what is causing this as well.

We need the two functionality because we will be processing thousands of PDF per month.

Our IDE is Delphi 7, windows xp 32 bit, using PDFToolKit VCL v4.0.1.145

Comment: Please contact the vendor for support

Comment: You can contact Gnostice Support at http://www.gnostice.com/support.asp

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have filled the PDF using Add signature option. You can use "Fill Blank signature field" option to fill an already existing empty signature field.